# Judgment of "not an answer"

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, multiple-questions

When a “[question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157042/is-a-screenshot-of-booking-com-acceptable-for-proof-of-accomodation/157047)” is actually four questions, none of which can actually be answered, should saying so really be deleted as "not an answer"?

Comment: Asking multiple questions is usually too broad and the question should therefore be closed. Nevertheless it's better to ask this on [travel's meta](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If a question cannot be answered, why are you submitting an answer, that doesn't actually answer the question?  An answer that does not answer the question should be downvoted and deleted IMO.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I clicked Meta on the Travel site, I did not realize it was taking me here.  If the downvotes are because I inadvertently asked on the wrong place, I can understand them.  If they are because I asked about the wisdom of an event, they are unjustified.

Comment: So, the consensus is clearly that the answer is "yes" but of the four answers that said so, one is hidden, alleging that it is not an answer.  Something is wrong here.  I was led to believe that the tag "discussion" implies that we can do that (although my entry clearly IS an answer).

Answer (score 19):

If that's all your answer contained...yes.  There's a close vote reason to the tune of, "Needs more focus" which covers this *exact* case.

If you want to commentate on a question's topicality, flagging/voting for closure is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 14):

If you were "saying so" in the answer box rather than by using a close vote or close flag, yes it should.

Answer (score 3):

Irrespective of whether any of the multiple questions in a question could be answered, I think that none should be while it is in that state. Instead I think such a question should be voted/flagged for closure using the **Needs more focus** close reason.

Once the question has been edited to reduce it to one clear question it will be suitable for users to vote/flag for re-opening, and ready to attract potential answerers.

Prior to that I think the area reserved for answers to a single, focused question should not be used.